# Card Probability with conditional

Tags: probability

Cards are dealt from a well shuffled standard deck means cards are drawn at random without replacement. Find the chance that:
The 51st card is red, given that the 32nd and 52nd cards are red

Solution attempt;
P(A the 51st card is red 24/50)\P(B of 32nd 26/52 and P(C of 52nd 25/51 Cards are red) =24/50*26/52*25/51= 0.1176

Total remaining cards of red is= 24, once 32nd and 52 are red.
of total 52 cards 50 remain is 50.
so P(51st is red)=24/50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: You are given that the $32$nd and $52$nd cards are red, so don't have to compute probabilities for those.  They just change the composition of the deck you are drawing from for the $51$st card (which might as well be the $3$rd).  How many total cards are left?  How many are red?

Comment: Total remaining cards of red is= 24, once 32nd and 52 are red.
of total 52 cards 50 remain is 50.
so P(51st is red)=24/50....is done and simple not compute probabilities conditional of 32nd and 52!

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Thanks-Rose Millikan it change my perception nnst...nnnd does not matter in conditional card probability computations!

Answer (score 1):

Since we can permute the cards around, the numbers 32, 51, 52 are distractions.

Under a suitable permutation, the question is equivalent to

"Find the chance that: The 3rd card is red, given that the 1st and 2nd card are red."

Comment: Thanks Calvin Lin it has given me new prospective in Statistics card probability distributors must be ignored at all times...!